# Java spring @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have a Spring Boot application with a class TokenProvider where i get some token from application.properties.
In another controller class TestController i need to create a object new TokenProvider and retrieve the value.
It gives me null values.
Why it doesn't work ?

PS: If i inject TokenProvider in TestController (with @Autowired JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider; )it works.

Why i cannot retrieve token without injecting ?

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtTokenProvider.class);

    @Value("${app.jwtSecret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    public String getJwtSecret() {
        return jwtSecret;
    }

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

//    @Autowired
//    JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get_propertie")
    public String getPropertie() {
        JwtTokenProvider jwt = new JwtTokenProvider();
        String res = "jwt" + jwt.getJwtSecret();
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

in case of creating `JwtTokenProvider` with `new` it is not being created by Spring and all annotations like `@Value` are basically being ignored - that's how Spring is working. What you can do is to create the `JwtTokenProvider` in proper Java `@Configuration` class providing `@Value String token` parameter

```
@Configuration
public class TokenConfig {
    @Bean
    public JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider(@Value("${app.jwtSecret}") token) {
        return new JwtTokenProvider(token); // or some setter depends on what the class provide
    }
}
```

but still - you need to use on of Spring dependency injection mechanism to have `@Value` working